# How to calculate the OOB of random forest?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am comparing some models to get a best model. Now, I want to get an OOB error of random forest model to compare it with the cross-validation errors of some others model. Can I do the comparison? If I can, how can I get the OOB error by R code?

Comment: try `model$err.rate[,1]` -  the i-th element being the (OOB) error rate for all trees up to the i-th. On a side note, while OOB should correlate with k-fold CV, I would still compare only k-fold CVs between models.

Comment: @missuse Thanks for your reply! But how to calculate the k-fold cv for random forest? Some guys use rfcv() function, but it seems that it is used to calculate cv errors to compare between random forest. But I have to compare the cv error of random forest with the cv errors of ridge model. What can I do?

Answer (score 11):

To get the OOB of a random forest model in R you can:

```
library(randomForest)

set.seed(1)
model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

OOB error is in:

```
model$err.rate[,1]
```

where the i-th element is the (OOB) error rate for all trees up to the i-th.

one can plot it and check if it is the same as the OOB in the plot method defined for rf models:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(model$err.rate[,1], type = "l")
plot(model)
```

[image]

OOB is useful for picking hyper parameters `mtry` and `ntree` and should correlate with k-fold CV but one should not use it to compare rf to different types of models tested by k-fold CV.
OOB is great since it is almost free as opposed to k-fold CV which takes k times to run.

An easy way to run a k-fold CV in R is:

define the folds (replace the 5 with k (positive integer >1) to run k -fold CV:

```
folds <- sample(1:5, size = nrow(iris), replace = T) #5 fold CV
```

this approach will not give equally sized folds (especially for smaller data sets), this is usually not a big deal.

```
table(folds)
#output
 1  2  3  4  5 
30 28 28 33 31
```

to remedy this:

```
folds <- sample(rep(1:5, length.out = nrow(iris)), size = nrow(iris), replace = F)

table(folds)
#output
 1  2  3  4  5 
30 30 30 30 30
```

run through the folds training the model on each of the 4 folds and prediction on the 5th. Here I just return a list of data frames containing the predictions and real values, one can customize the call to return any statistic he desires.

```
CV_rf <- lapply(1:5, function(x){ #5 corresponds to the number of folds defined earlier
  model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris[folds != x,])
  preds <- predict(model,  iris[folds == x,], type="response")
  return(data.frame(preds, real = iris$Species[folds == x]))
  })
```

You can use the same code to get the performance of the ridge model.

convert list of data frames to a data frame:

```
CV_rf <- do.call(rbind, CV_rf)
```

check accuracy

```
caret::confusionMatrix(CV_rf$preds, CV_rf$real) 
#part of output:
Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.9533         
                 95% CI : (0.9062, 0.981)
    No Information Rate : 0.3333         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16
```

so here the accuracy is 0.9533

while the OOB for the 500th (500 is fit by default in rf) tree was:

```
model$err.rate[500,1]
#OOB 
0.04666667
```

They are the same defeating my point completely, but for instance try to run 10 fold CV or 3 fold and you will see they are not the same.

another approach is to use `caret` or `mlr` libraries. I don't use `mlr` but `caret` is really good for tasks like this. Here is [something](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/) to get you started with caret and rf. Additionally caret has excellent [documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html). I can recommend it even if you do not plan to use the package.

Comment: I don't have err.rate in the rf model object when I used xtest and ytest, how do I get OOB r2?

Comment: If you need OOB do not use `xtest` and `ytest` arguments, rather use predict on the generated model to get predictions for test set.

Comment: Is there a way how to extract the OOB error from the `finalModel` produced by `caret` similar to `model$err.rate[500,1]` when using a model directly trained using `randomForest`? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkH does `tail(caretTrainOutout$finalModel$err.rate[,1], 1)` work?

Comment: @missuse, I had the same idea but it does not work. While my model object has a fit object `finalModel` this does not contain an `err.rate` item and the suggested code returns `NULL`. Inside the `finalModel` there are two vectors of length `ntree`: `mse` and `rsq` but the [caret documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf) does not go beyond the level of the `finalModel`  so I'm not sure what those really are and if and how they can be used to access the oob error.

Comment: @missuse, I just found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319446/inconsistent-out-of-bag-error-estimates), maybe there is no other way to squeeze oob errors out of a caret-trained RF... seems strange though